# How to set AM and PM only in One Datetimepicker using VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net, datetimepicker

How can i set the period (AM/PM) to one only, like one datetimepicker set to only AM and the other one to PM only and cannot be changed to AM if PM or PM if AM...

Comment: Use the CustomFormat property, like "h:mm tt"

Comment: Do you mean you want to (for example) restrict the times that the user can enter to PM (12:00 to 23:59)?

Comment: Like you said, @Blackwood, I think he wants to have two separate DateTimePickers, where in the first one you can only enter AM time, and in the second one only PM time.

Comment: @Blackwood, yes sir.

Comment: @VisualVincent, Your right. I have two DateTimePickers the AM only and PM only. Is it possible ?

Comment: Not that I am aware of, you'd have to do some kind of workaround. Perhaps check what time the user has inputted when the [ValueChanged event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datetimepicker.valuechanged(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1) is raised.